# Test REST api call using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jasmine

I am trying to test a REST api call using Jasmine. Can anyone please explain how to deal with a asynchronous test like this using Jasmine?

==============================answer.js==============================

```html
var conf = require('../config');
var req = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

function base64_encode(file) {
 var file = fs.readFileSync(file);
 return new Buffer(file).toString('base64');
}

var answers = function (){
 this.getAnswer = function(id, branchId, locale, question, deviceId){
  var answer;
  req({
   url : conf.baseUrl + '/api/v1/answers',
   method : 'POST',
      headers: {
          'content-type': 'text/plain',
      },
   body : JSON.stringify({
    id : id,
    branchId : branchId,
    locale : locale,
    question : base64_encode("./" + question + ".wav"),
    deviceId : deviceId
   })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
   if (error) {
    console.log(error);
   } else {
    answer = JSON.parse(body).answer;
    console.log(JSON.parse(body).responseText);
    fs.writeFile("../answer.wav", answer, 'base64',
    function(err) {
     if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
     }
     console.log("file saved successfully!");
    });
   }
  });
  return answer;
 }
}

module.exports = new answers();
```

=======================loan_application_spec.js======================

```html
var answers_api = require('../requests/answers');

describe("Loan application", function() {
 it("Ask about loans", function() {
  console.log(answers_api.getAnswer("1234", "HLB_02", "en-US", "input", "robot_01"));
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd modified it a bit to suit the testing.

- I changed the answers to be an object and not a function. But I still
  use the new keyword to instantiate for the ease of testing
- May be if you could refactor the req object's implementation, it
  might be easier for you to test

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580540/how-to-spy-on-anonymous-function-using-jasmine) that helped me construct this answer.

```
    var conf = require('../config');
    var req = require('request');
    var fs = require('fs');

    function base64_encode(file) {
    var file = fs.readFileSync(file);
     return new Buffer(file).toString('base64');
    }

    var answers = {
    ans: "",
    getAnswer : function(id, branchId, locale, question, deviceId){
        var answer;     
        req({
            url : conf.baseUrl + '/api/v1/answers',
            method : 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'text/plain',
            },
            body : JSON.stringify({
                id : id,
                branchId : branchId,
                locale : locale,
                question : base64_encode("./" + question + ".wav"),
                deviceId : deviceId
            })
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                answer = JSON.parse(body).answer;
                console.log(JSON.parse(body).responseText);
                fs.writeFile("../answer.wav", answer, 'base64',
                function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log("file saved successfully!");
                });
            }
        });
        this.ans = answer;
        return answer;
      }
    }

    return module.exports = Object.create(answers);

    //Jasmine test

    var answers_api = require('../requests/answers');

    describe("Loan application", function() {
        it("Ask about loans", function() {
        req = jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function() {
            answers_api.ans = true // actually make this answer whatever you expect it to be.
        });
        var testObj = answers_api.getAnswer("1234", "HLB_02", "en-US", "input", "robot_01"));
        expect(req).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(answers_api.ans).toBe(true)
      });
    });
```

Comment: there are syntax errors in this.getAnswer = function and return module.exports = Object.create(answers); lines.

Also I get the following error with the Jasmine code you have specified.
    TypeError: jasmine.createSpy(...).andCallFake is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: I've made some minor corrections to the answer. Please try it now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still there is a syntax error with return keyword with module.exports = Object.create(answers);

Also when I execute removing return, I get the following output

Comment: Failures:
1) Loan application Ask about loans
  Message:
    Expected spy unknown to have been called.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected spy unknown to have been called.
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\eclipse\hlbApiTester\spec\loan_application_spec.js:9:17)
  Message:
    Expected undefined to be true.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected undefined to be true.
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\eclipse\hlbApiTester\spec\loan_application_spec.js:10:29)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.018 seconds